# Confusion regarding threads and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

To understand the concept of threads better, we are supposed to use a Number object that can be increased, decreased, squared and rooted via it's methods. It's only attribute is a double number (initialized as number=1).

So if i instantiate the Number object and call increment(), decrement(), square() and root() 100000000 times to that number object, the number attribute is 1 again (as expected).

Now the problem is that we are supposed to instantiate two thread objects, one calling the increase/decrease 100000000 times and the other one calling square/root 100000000 times. 
According to our teacher the result would be inconsistency, i.E getting 0 instead of 1 as the result, but in my program it just gives me infinity or 1 depending on wether or not i am using synchronized() in the Thread class.

```
public class Calculation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Number num = new Number();
        Number num1 = new Number();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            num.increment();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            num.decrement();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            num.square();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
            num.root();
        }
        System.out.println(num.getNumber());
        CalcThread t1 = new CalcThread(num1, true);
        CalcThread t2 = new CalcThread(num1, false);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(num1.getNumber());   
    }
}
```

```
public class CalcThread extends Thread {
    public Number num;
    public boolean decision;

    public CalcThread(Number num, boolean decision) {
        this.num = num;
        this.decision = decision;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(num) {
        if (this.decision) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                num.square();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                num.root();
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                num.increment();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
                num.decrement();
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Number {
    double number;
    public Number() {
        this.number = 1;    
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.number++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        this.number--;
    }

    public void square() {
        this.number = this.number * this.number;
    }

    public void root() {
        this.number = Math.sqrt(this.number);
    }

    public double getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Getting infinity when leaving synchronized out makes sense because it is increasing while squaring the number at the same time, so the number will soon be too large to fit the double type size right?
How do i get the inconsistency my teacher was talking about?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Ja, it seems so. To make the things really unpredictable you could add booleans to decide randomly on one hand wether to square or to root and on the other hand wether to increment or decrement. Then it will look really unpredictable

Comment: You've seen the inconsistency. When the code that makes changes to the variable is inside a synchronised block/method, everything works as expected. However when you remove that 'thread safety' mechanism, you see that the results are not what you previously observed.

Comment: if you remove the synchronized you will see the inconsistencies you want. If you don't, inset a random small sleep() between each loop inside your method and run more thread.

Comment: > How do i get the inconsistency my teacher was talking about?< A multi-threaded program is guaranteed to behave in a certain way if it follows all of the "synchronization" rules. But it is _not_ guaranteed to behave in any particular way if it breaks the rules. Testing multi-threaded programs for correctness is mostly futile, because a program that breaks the rules still might work correctly on one day, but not on another. It might work correctly on one operating system, but not on another. It might work correctly when the system is lightly loaded, but not when heavily loaded, etc.

Comment: Thats not the point, i understand that it should be inconsistent but if I remove the synchronized() part of the code I just get infinity as a result all the time, which is not inconsistent.

Comment: >According to our teacher the result would be inconsistency...How do i get the inconsistency my teacher was talking about?< Have you asked your teacher what "inconsistency" is supposed to mean? I think maybe you expect it to mean you'd get a different result every time you ran the program. But maybe that is not what your teacher meant.